# Use terminal command to verify software

Tags: mac-os, terminal

I've seen that it is possible to use terminal command to verify software instead of using the IDE. Something like `arduino --verify lab.ino`.
Is there a way to do so on Mac OS?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I managed to verify code from terminal by invoking `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino --verify lab.ino` BUT this command automatically starts the IDE and exits it afterwards. Even with an IDE instance open it will start a new one. This is annoying since it will switch the active workspace away, but it kinda works. See [arduino manpage](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc).

Answer (score 0):

Use AVRDude, and set the `op` field to `v` for verify. E.g.:

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.usbserial-A703114N -b57600 -D -Uflash:v:/var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/build7a7055aab8d0564b6a7844b201562ffe.tmp/CV-turner.ino.hex:i
```

change `/dev/cu.usbserial-A703114N` to your serial port.

change `/var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/build7a7055aab8d0564b6a7844b201562ffe.tmp/CV-turner.ino.hex` to your hex file.

More info on avrdude at http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html#Option-Descriptions

Sample output would be:

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 14 2015 at 16:30:25
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Volumes/Lion-Data/home/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbserial-A703114N
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.16
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 0
avrdude: verifying flash memory against /var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/build7a7055aab8d0564b6a7844b201562ffe.tmp/CV-turner.ino.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file /var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/build7a7055aab8d0564b6a7844b201562ffe.tmp/CV-turner.ino.hex:
avrdude: input file /var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/build7a7055aab8d0564b6a7844b201562ffe.tmp/CV-turner.ino.hex contains 7902 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 3.34s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0002
         0x64 != 0x6a
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:00, E:00, L:00)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Notice the `verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0002`

PS. you need an actual `hex` file, not an `ino` file. Different compilers and different versions of the Arduino IDE can produce slightly different hex files, for the exact same C-program.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he's after - I think he wants to "verify" (i.e., compile) his sketch from the command line.

Comment: @Gerben I am sorry but I dont have an arduino, I realy just want to verify my code. I am coding for a project and just want to commit verified code.